# Calculating shortest path in Networkx given custom edge weight

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to assign length property to each edge and based on those lengths calculate the shortest path from node X to node Y.

However, I am not sure how to correctly reference the length properties that I specified in this part of the code:
`nx.shortest_path(G,source='Dehli',target='Pune', weight = ?????)`

#### Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["Dehli","Ahmadabad","Kolkata",'Bangalore','Pune','Maduraj'])
G.add_edge('Dehli', 'Ahmadabad', length =890)
G.add_edge('Dehli', 'Kolkata', length =1422)
G.add_edge('Dehli', 'Bangalore', length =2168)
G.add_edge('Dehli', 'Pune', length =1450)
G.add_edge('Dehli', 'Maduraj', length = 2603)

G.add_edge('Ahmadabad', 'Kolkata', length =1902)
G.add_edge('Ahmadabad', 'Bangalore', length =1403)
G.add_edge('Ahmadabad', 'Pune', length =624)
G.add_edge('Ahmadabad', 'Maduraj', length =1807)
G.add_edge('Kolkata', 'Bangalore', length =1778)
G.add_edge('Kolkata', 'Pune', length =1782)
G.add_edge('Kolkata', 'Maduraj', length =2043)

G.add_edge('Bangalore', 'Pune', length =824)
G.add_edge('Bangalore', 'Maduraj', length =404)
G.add_edge('Pune', 'Maduraj', length =1195)



nx.draw(G,pos,node_color='k')

path = nx.shortest_path(G,source='Dehli',target='Pune')
path_edges = zip(path,path[1:])
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=path,node_color='g')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=path_edges,edge_color='g',width=7)
print(nx.shortest_path_length(G,source='Dehli',target='Pune'))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html), a call to `shortest_path` is of the form `shortest_path(G, source=None, target=None, weight=None)`

The optional argument `weight` is

> **weight** (None or string, optional (default = None)) – If None, every edge has weight/distance/cost 1. If a string, use this edge attribute as the edge weight. Any edge attribute not present defaults to 1.

So in your case, call it as `path = nx.shortest_path(G,source='Dehli',target='Pune', weight='length')`.  Note that Networkx takes the edge attribute `length=X` and stores it in a dictionary with the key `'length'` (a string) and the value `X`.

Comment: Thank You!  I did not put parentheses around the length and this fixed all problems